# Webclient local object will .Net garbage collect before file download?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question about following code. It uses Webclient to request a file download. The file is downloaded asynchronously.

I want to know if Webclient object is likely to be garbage collected by .Net runtime ? Since the method will exit before download is complete and there is no way to access webclient object again. Is it enough for .Net to GC it ?

Even though I can safely make it a member of class but I want to know if my understanding is correct ?

```
    private void button_Update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        try
        {
            String filename = Path.GetFileName(status.Url);
            string tempPath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();
            String downloadedFile = Path.Combine(tempPath, filename);

            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadProgressChanged);
            webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadFileCompleted);
            webClient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(status.Url), downloadedFile, downloadedFile);
            this.button_Skip.Enabled = false;
            this.button_Update.Enabled = false;


        }
        catch
        {
            DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I know of is Raymond Chen's blog post: [When does an object become available for garbage collection?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx)

This article makes the following (perhaps surprising!) points:

> An object in a block of code can become eligible for collection *during execution of a function it called*.

...

> A parameter to a method can become eligible for collection *while the method is still executing*.

...

> An object can become eligible for collection *during execution of a method on that very object*.

Now, some or all of these statements may not be true in this specific case, but as a general rule of thumb you shouldn't try to second-guess the garbage collector. If you need the `WebClient` to stick around until a certain condition is met, then the safest route is to make sure you store a strong reference to it until that condition is met.